# VBA Excel If statement with AND/OR function

Tags: excel, vba

Just want to know your idea on this matter. So the thing is I'm trying to show the information in the `UserForm` with the `MultiPage` control. I have a `Cert` sheet where the data are stored. So in the `Cert` sheet, the count of the data can be equals to `1`, `2`, or `3`. I already figured out the flow for `1` and `3` but I'm having a problem with the `2`.

My plan is like this:

- If the `data` = `2` then

  - If `box` = `1` or `box` = `2` Then

    - Show data in first and second box
  - If `box` = `1` or `box` = `3` Then

    - Show data in first and third box
  - If `box` = `2` or `box` = `3` Then

    - Show data in second and third box

Here's a visual for your guide.

**USERFORM:** If the data is equal to `2` or `3`, data should be shown in their respective boxes.

[image: UserForm]

**SHEET DATA:**

[image: Sheet Data]

The code below is the one that I'm currently using for `2`.

```
For r = 9 To Lastrow

    If Application.CountIf(Worksheets(ws_output).Columns(3), LRN) = 2 Then        'data
    
        If _
            ws.Cells(r, 3) = CStr( ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("K11").value ) And _
            ( ws.Cells(r, 12).value = 1 Or ws.Cells(r, 12).value = 2 ) _
        Then
    
            If ws.Cells(r, 12).value = 1 Then        'show the data with the value of 1
                'FIRST BOX
                txtBox_LRN.Text = ws.Cells(r, 3).value
                txtBox_name.Text = ws.Cells(r, 4).value
                txtBox_grd.Text = ws.Cells(r, 5).value
    
            ElseIf ws.Cells(r, 12).value = 2 Then        'show the data with the value of 2
                'SECOND BOX
                sb_txtBox_LRN.Text = ws.Cells(r, 3).value
                sb_txtBox_name.Text = ws.Cells(r, 4).value
                sb_txtBox_grd.Text = ws.Cells(r, 5).value
            End If

        ElseIf _
            ws.Cells(r, 3) = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("K11").value) And _
           ( ws.Cells(r, 12).value = 1 Or ws.Cells(r, 12).value = 3 ) _
        Then

            If ws.Cells(r, 12).value = 1 Then        'show the data with the value of 1
                'FIRST BOX
                txtBox_LRN.Text = ws.Cells(r, 3).value
                txtBox_name.Text = ws.Cells(r, 4).value
                txtBox_grd.Text = ws.Cells(r, 5).value

            ElseIf ws.Cells(r, 12).value = 2 Then        'show the data with the value of 3
                'THIRD BOX
                tb_txtBox_LRN.Text = ws.Cells(r, 3).value
                tb_txtBox_name.Text = ws.Cells(r, 4).value
                tb_txtBox_grd.Text = ws.Cells(r, 5).value
            End If

        ElseIf _
            ws.Cells(r, 3) = CStr( ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("K11").value ) And _
           ( ws.Cells(r, 12).value = 2 Or ws.Cells(r, 12).value = 3 ) _
        Then

            If ws.Cells(r, 12).value = 2 Then        'show the data with the value of 2
                'SECOND BOX
                sb_txtBox_LRN.Text = ws.Cells(r, 3).value
                sb_txtBox_name.Text = ws.Cells(r, 4).value
                sb_txtBox_grd.Text = ws.Cells(r, 5).value

            ElseIf ws.Cells(r, 12).value = 3 Then        'show the data with the value of 3
                'THIRD BOX
                tb_txtBox_LRN.Text = ws.Cells(r, 3).value
                tb_txtBox_name.Text = ws.Cells(r, 4).value
                tb_txtBox_grd.Text = ws.Cells(r, 5).value
            End If

        End If
    End If

Next r
```

The `If box = 1 or box = 2 Then` and `If box = 1 or box = 3 Then` are working but I'm having a problem with `If box = 2 or box = 3 Then`:

- If `data = 2`, it runs in the first `IF statement` with the this code:

  ```
  (ws.Cells(r, 12).value = 1 Or ws.Cells(r, 12).value = 2)
  ```
- or if the `data = 3`, it runs in this code:

  ```
  (ws.Cells(r, 12).value = 1 Or ws.Cells(r, 12).value = 3)
  ```
- But how can I make it run with this?:

  ```
  (ws.Cells(r, 12).value = 2 Or ws.Cells(r, 12).value = 3) Then
  ```

Comment: You can make your program **a lot simpler** if you cache the `ws.Cells(...)` value first.

Comment: @Dai Can you explain it more? I'm new to VBA.

Comment: I'm saying you should store `ws.Cells(r, 12).value` into a temporary variable so you don't need to keep on typing-out `ws.Cells(r, 12).value` everywhere.

Comment: @Dai Ohhh right. Noted with that. I'll revise my code. Thank you for that. :)

Comment: In your second main If block (box is 1 or 3) you first test for 1 but then you test for 2?  The whole thing seems too complex though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *seems* to be what your code is doing but I'm not sure it's correct...

```vba
Dim box, kValue

If Application.CountIf(Worksheets(ws_output).Columns(3), LRN) = 2 Then        'data

    kValue =  CStr( ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("K11").value )

    For r = 9 To Lastrow

        If ws.Cells(r, 3) = kValue Then

            box = ws.Cells(r, 12).value

            If box = 1 Then
                txtBox_LRN.Text = ws.Cells(r, 3).value
                txtBox_name.Text = ws.Cells(r, 4).value
                txtBox_grd.Text = ws.Cells(r, 5).value
            Elseif box = 2 Then
                sb_txtBox_LRN.Text = ws.Cells(r, 3).value
                sb_txtBox_name.Text = ws.Cells(r, 4).value
                sb_txtBox_grd.Text = ws.Cells(r, 5).value
            Elseif box = 3 Then
                tb_txtBox_LRN.Text = ws.Cells(r, 3).value
                tb_txtBox_name.Text = ws.Cells(r, 4).value
                tb_txtBox_grd.Text = ws.Cells(r, 5).value
            End if

        end if

    Next r
end if
```

EDIT - slightly shorter:

```vba
Dim box As Long, kValue, pref As String

If Application.CountIf(Worksheets(ws_output).Columns(3), LRN) = 2 Then        'data

    kValue = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HOME").Range("K11").Value)

    For r = 9 To Lastrow
        If ws.Cells(r, 3) = kValue Then
            box = ws.Cells(r, 12).Value
            If box >= 1 And box <= 3 Then
                pref = Array("", "sb_", "tb_")(box - 1)                      'get the control name prefix
                Me.Controls(pref & "txtBox_LRN").Text = ws.Cells(r, 3).Value 'reference controls by name...
                Me.Controls(pref & "txtBox_name").Text = ws.Cells(r, 4).Value
                Me.Controls(pref & "txtBox_grd").Text = ws.Cells(r, 5).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End If
```

Comment: This seems to be not right. I put a visual to the question for reference.

Comment: My mistake! This seems to kinda work, but still need some revisions to my codes.